# How to catch transaction errors?

Tags: eosjs, cpu

I'm trying to send a specific number of transactions per day to a smart contract.
Because of low CPU stake I easily get CPU error.
My goal is to catch this error and handle it in order to keep trying sending transactions until CPU allows it.

```
     try {
        const res = await api.transact(objTrans, {blocksBehind: 3,expireSeconds: 30})
        //do something
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('\nCaught exception: ' + e);
        if (error instanceof RpcError) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json, null, 2));
          //send another transaction
        }
      }
```

This is what i'm trying to achieve, i tried this but the program just shuts whenever an error occurs.